# Changing the pixel on a map - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am new to Objective C and could use any help.

I am trying to change the color of a pixel on my screen.
I currently have a indoor map on my screen using an Image View object.

I would like to represent each of the nodes on my map as a color (Example: all the nodes are either red, blue, green, etc).

I want to be able to get the coordinates of each of the nodes on my screen and put it into an array.

Once I know my path I want to get the coordinates of the nodes that will be used in my path and make it a different color. (All the non-path nodes are red, while the path nodes are green).

Could someone help me figure out how to change the pixel's color on the screen?
I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: This sounds like something you should do with [CoreGraphics/Quartz2D](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html), which is a C-level API that takes some getting used to before you'll be comfortable with it. [Here's a good collection of tutorials for people just getting into CoreGraphics](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tag/core-graphics).

Comment: How do i implement the coreGraphics features onto my app